# Como limpar campos de formulário em c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou fazendo um projeto para a faculdade, criei um `GroupBox` e dentro tem `RadioButton`, `Label`, `MaskedTexbox` e `TextBox`. Quando clico no botão cancelar fiz a limpeza do `MaskTexbox` e `TextBox` e desabilito o `Textbox`. Ele só limpa e tive que repetir o código para limpar segue abaixo.

```
private void toolStripButtonCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rdbAprovadoAberto.Enabled = false;
    rdbReprovadoAberto.Enabled = false;
    lblNomeUser.Text = "Sistema";

    maskDataAprovReprov.Text = "";// limpa o campo MaskedTextBox
    txtMotivoReprovaAberto.Text = "";// limpa o campo TextBox
    this.txtMotivoReprovaAberto.Enabled = false;

    // tenho que duplicar o código senão não limpa os campos e desabilita txtMotivoReprovaAberto

    rdbAbertoAberto.Checked = true;
    maskDataAprovReprov.Text = "";
    txtMotivoReprovaAberto.Text = "";
    txtMotivoReprovaAberto.Enabled = false;
}
```

e isso também deu certo mais não sei se é boas Práticas

```
private void toolStripButtonCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    rdbAprovadoAberto.Enabled = false;
    rdbReprovadoAberto.Enabled = false;
    lblNomeUser.Text = "Sistema";

    if (rdbAprovadoAberto.Checked)
    {
        maskDataAprovReprov.Text = "";
    }

    if (rdbReprovadoAberto.Checked)
    {
        maskDataAprovReprov.Text = "";
        txtMotivoReprovaAberto.Text = "";
        txtMotivoReprovaAberto.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Leia seu texto com calma, pense que você não conhece os detalhes do programa. Você acha que dá para entender? O texto não parece fazer muito sentido. Eu não consegui entender se você quer algo mais do que está fazendo e se algo está errado. Além disto dependendo do que você realmente quer este trecho isolado não ajude entender o problema. O que posso adiantar é que este trecho está limpando os dados e está marcando um botão do rádio como ligado.

Answer (score 2):

Gosto de fazer um método genérico. Por exemplo, no código a seguir eu limpo todas as caixas de textos de um `FORM`. Você pode colocar outras condições para verificar outros tipos de componentes do `FORM` e fazer o que você deseja.

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c.GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Form.Textbox")
    {
        c.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quebre seu código mais, para facilitar a leitura. Quanto menor o código mais fácil de entender e debugar.

Ai você pode ir melhorando aos poucos. fica melhorar para visualizar código duplicado ou código (nesse caso as funções) com mais de uma responsabilidade.

Muitas condições na mesma função pode deixar seu código pouco legível e difícil de manutenção.

Answer (score 1):

Costumo criar um método somente para limpeza. Há como fazer métodos genéricos, para todos os controles, mas eu faço um para cada situação, vai da sua preferência.

Evite usar `TextBox1.Text = "";` ao invés prefira usar: `TextBox1.Text  = string.Empty;` além de ficar mais elegante, evita de você sem querer pressionar a barra de espaço entre as aspas e aí mela todo seu código.

Crie métodos somente para isso, não limpe no click do botão cancelar como você fez, ao invés, chame o método de limpeza apenas.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize `TextBox1.Text  = string.Empty;`

se for vários faça assim:

```
 public void limpaCampos()
 {
   TextBox1.Text  = 
   TextBox2.Text  = 
   TextBox3.Text  = 
   TextBoxn.Text  = string.Empty;
 }
```